# simplify and rearrange my google script for faster process this often stucks in the middle of the process

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Can anyone simplify and rearrange my script such that it works faster without stucking . This script was made to extract spreadsheet data from 4 spreadsheets and deleting blank rows based on a column criteria, This script is working well but taking long time and suddenly/often breaks process saying that spreadsheet page needs to refresh thus stopping the entire process. which should follow with rerunning the script. - Thanks in advance.

my script is as follows :

```
function myFunction() {
// spreadsheets key to extract data.
//Bhaskar      0AjkkHlm3kCphdFh3M2dtRDdoZHhWZlg5UzFjSWZFcVE
//RAmohan      0AjkkHlm3kCphdGFlNTVhSDc5VXVTeS0xc2ZISDRGZlE
//Krishnareddy 0AjkkHlm3kCphdEhDWEllalpoM3VmNE5weUNLZkd4TVE
//Suni          0AjkkHlm3kCphdFUxTXJlN3lGYkRMY2NXUUkzSTVfbEE

    var copieddata = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjkkHlm3kCphdFh3M2dtRDdoZHhWZlg5UzFjSWZFcVE').
                    getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();
                //getSheetByName('List').getRange('I6:AT500').getValues();      

    var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
                SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(s1);
            //getRange(StartingROWS(1,2,3,4,...),StartingCOLUMNS(A,B,C,D..),  

           s1.getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).setValues(copieddata);


    //var col1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumColumns();
    //var row1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumRows();

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
// here ends sheet 1  -------

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var numRows  = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var datasheet  = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = datasheet.getValues();

//Browser.msgBox(" data lenght -" + data.length + " rage is " + datasheet);

    for (var i = data.length; i > 0; --i){ 
        var ii=i-1;
        var row = data[ii]; 
        var name = row[6]; 
        var len = name.length;

        //Browser.msgBox("row number" + i + " ->" + row[10] + "<- its length =" + len);

        if(name.length!=3){ 
            //Browser.msgBox("delete ." + i);
            sheet.deleteRow(i);
        } 
   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
     } 
   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written


// ------------------


    var lrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

//Browser.msgBox("l range - " + lrange); 

    var copieddata = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjkkHlm3kCphdGFlNTVhSDc5VXVTeS0xc2ZISDRGZlE').
                    getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();

    var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
                SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(s1);

        s1.getRange((lrange+1),1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).setValues(copieddata);


    //var col1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumColumns();
    //var row1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumRows();

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
// here ends sheet 2  -------

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var numRows  = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var datasheet  = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = datasheet.getValues();

//Browser.msgBox(" data lenght -" + data.length + " rage is " + datasheet);

    for (var i = data.length; i > 0; --i){ 
        var ii=i-1;
        var row = data[ii]; 
        var name = row[6]; 
        var len = name.length;

        //Browser.msgBox("row number" + i + " ->" + row[10] + "<- its length =" + len);

        if(name.length!=3){ 
            //Browser.msgBox("delete ." + i);
            sheet.deleteRow(i);
        } 
   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
     } 


// ------------------


    var lrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

//Browser.msgBox("l range - " + lrange); 

    var copieddata = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjkkHlm3kCphdEhDWEllalpoM3VmNE5weUNLZkd4TVE').
                    getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();

    var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
                SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(s1);

        s1.getRange((lrange+1),1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).setValues(copieddata);


    //var col1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumColumns();
    //var row1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumRows();

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written  
// here ends sheet 3  -------

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var numRows  = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var datasheet  = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = datasheet.getValues();

//Browser.msgBox(" data lenght -" + data.length + " rage is " + datasheet);

    for (var i = data.length; i > 0; --i){ 
        var ii=i-1;
        var row = data[ii]; 
        var name = row[6]; 
        var len = name.length;

        //Browser.msgBox("row number" + i + " ->" + row[10] + "<- its length =" + len);

        if(name.length!=3){ 
            //Browser.msgBox("delete ." + i);
            sheet.deleteRow(i);
        } 
   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
     } 


// ------------------

    var lrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

//Browser.msgBox("l range - " + lrange); 

    var copieddata = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjkkHlm3kCphdFUxTXJlN3lGYkRMY2NXUUkzSTVfbEE').
                    getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();

    var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
                SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(s1);

        s1.getRange((lrange+1),1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).setValues(copieddata);


    //var col1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumColumns();
    //var row1count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,copieddata.length,copieddata[0].length).getNumRows();

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written  
// here ends sheet 4  -------

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var numRows  = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var datasheet  = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = datasheet.getValues();

//Browser.msgBox(" data lenght -" + data.length + " rage is " + datasheet);

    for (var i = data.length; i > 0; --i){ 
        var ii=i-1;
        var row = data[ii]; 
        var name = row[6]; 
        var len = name.length;

        //Browser.msgBox("row number" + i + " ->" + row[10] + "<- its length =" + len);

        if(name.length!=3){ 
            //Browser.msgBox("delete ." + i);
            sheet.deleteRow(i);
        } 
   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
     } 
}
```

spreadsheet link is as follows : [Clik here to enter into my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjkkHlm3kCphdGtmOWxNNDhmM2h6ZTZKQlpsbVZUVUE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's my attempt:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var source = ['0AjkkHlm3kCphdFh3M2dtRDdoZHhWZlg5UzFjSWZFcVE',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdGFlNTVhSDc5VXVTeS0xc2ZISDRGZlE',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdEhDWEllalpoM3VmNE5weUNLZkd4TVE',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdFUxTXJlN3lGYkRMY2NXUUkzSTVfbEE'];
  var copied = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    copied = copied.concat(SpreadsheetApp.openById(source[i]).getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues());
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < copied.length; j++) {
    if (copied[j][6].length != 3) {
      copied.splice(j, 1);
      j--;
    }
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, copied.length, copied[0].length).setValues(copied);
}
```

In this I create one big javascript array from the four spreadsheets, remove elements ("rows") from that array (rather than deleting rows in the spreadsheet itself which I presume is the reason why it's slow), clear the destination sheet, and set the values of the modified array in one go.

HTH
Adam

Comment: Amazing!! Surprised to see the fastness!! Thank you Mr.AdamL, Thanks a "TON".

Comment: I don't know what best practice is on this forum, but rather than submitting another answer to a new question, I have taken the liberty of entering "myFunction3" into your spreadsheet for you to try out.

Comment: At the same time can you please suggest me how to filter and copy four different rows of data namely "GEN","BCD","INC","PLA" based on column 6 should be copied directly to sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4 within the same script above (data accumulated from group different spreadsheets into one spreadsheet) This i have tried to do with the same script by just adding 'code' 
    if (copied[j][6].length != 3 && copied[j][6].trim == 'GEN' ) {
           but it is not validating properly, instead it is copying every ting.    -Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have edited your comment after I posted mine, but my comment was replying to this second request (just to avoid confusion).

Comment: I have gone through the function, Thank you very much for your support & Help in solving my problem! Thanks a lot. Finally sorry if i have troubled you anytime.